# node.js/typescript can not find local module

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-webkit

When I try to import a local file it either throws an error at runtime but compiling it using tsc works. When I make it work for node.js, typescript throws an error at compile time.

When I do

```
import A = require("./A");
```

node.js complains, that it can not find the A module and typescript compiles just fine.

But when I change it to

```
import A = require("./js/A");
```

node.js can find the module but Typescript tells me there is an error.

The layout is like this:

```
js
\- A.ts
\- B.ts
```

I compile the files separately and I already tried searching for changing the root directory for the typescript compiler but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Are you trying to import A into B? If so you should do `import A = require("A");`

Comment: @Martin if I do that typescript compiles but then the node.js code doesn't work because node.js expects internal modules to be paths relative to the root of the directory ("./js/A"), but typescripts expects it relative to the typescript file ("./A")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing how you are compiling the TypeScript, and without seeing how you are attempting to `require()` these files from node, it's hard to answer this question.

Even so, I can tell you that *both* TypeScript and node.js are expecting `require()` to be given a path which is **relative to the file doing the require**.

If I were to have a js/A.ts that looked like so:

```
import B = require("./B");
console.log(B.thing);
```

And a js/B.ts that looked like so:

```
var myStuff = {
    thing: "I'm a thing!"
}
export = myStuff;
```

I could then compile *both* files with a single `tsc -m commonjs ./js/A.ts`

And then I could run node with: `node ./js/A.js` and would see the output:

```
I'm a thing!
```

Comment: Ok just tried, vanilla nodejs works fine but using node-webkit it doesn't work.

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Differences-of-JavaScript-contexts

Comment: @WebFreak001 how are you loading the js files in node-webkit?  You still have to use `require()` for those.  If you put the path to the TypeScript compiled js into a `<script src={path_to_js}>` it will screw up the module loading.

Comment: yeah i did that, changed it to require now